# Logging Output From Terminal Persistent PHP Script

Tags: php, terminal

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717167/how-to-keep-a-persistent-php-script-running) shows how to run a persistent PHP script. However, is there a way to also write the output to a text file? I've tried running `nohup php hello_world.php & > &1 > output.txt`, but I get `syntax error near unexpected token '&'`. If I remove the `&`, the output is logged, but the script only runs once. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
nohup php hello_world.php > output.txt &
```